# how to make distinct in django orm extra?

Tags: python, django

I want to select distint from this query, to show the "month"

```
cekbulan = Transaksi.objects.filter(tanggal__range=["2016-07-01", "2017-06-30"], unit='03').extra(
    select={'month': "month(date)"}).distinct()
```

it is my template

```
    <table>
       {% for bulanmaxs in cekbulan %}
           <tr>
               <td>{{ bulanmaxs.month }}</td>
           </tr>
       {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

but it didn't work to distinct value, it still list all date from my database, how to resolve it?

Comment: Look up documentation for Annotate (date annotation in your case).

Comment: i think annotate is not support for distinct @AndreyShipilov

Comment: You can add distinct = true as a parameter. Also read about distinct(), maybe it will help with understanding.

Comment: @Gusan of course it does. Read the docs first.

Comment: This might help you: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24431

Comment: `Transaksi.objects.filter(tanggal__range=["2016-07-01", "2017-06-30"], unit='03').extra(select={'month': "month(date)"}).values('month').distinct()` This should work in your case if you only want distinct months in your template

Comment: thank you @anupsabraham its work now

Comment: Ok. I will add it as an answer.

Comment: allright @anupsabraham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

> On PostgreSQL only, you can pass positional arguments (*fields) in order to specify the names of fields to which the DISTINCT should apply. This translates to a SELECT DISTINCT ON SQL query. Here’s the difference. For a normal distinct() call, the database compares each field in each row when determining which rows are distinct. For a distinct() call with specified field names, the database will only compare the specified field names.

If you only want distinct months in your template, you can specify that you only want months and then do a distinct operation on it.

```
cekbulan = Transaksi.objects.filter(tanggal__range=["2016-07-01", "2017-06-30"], unit='03').extra(select={'month': "month(date)"}).values('month').distinct()
```